# Sensor Fusion on Android 4

Tags: android, sensors

it seems that a proper sensor fusion for accelerometer/gyro/compass is already implemented in SDK level 15:

[link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17780)

On that thread they refer to the android source code:

*"frameworks/base/services/sensorservice: the gravity, orientation and rotation vector virtual sensors are now based on a Kalman filter fusing accelerometer/gyro/compass readings"*

But I really cannot find the folder hierachy *"frameworks/base/services/sensorservice:"*?!!

Can someone help me?
Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Ok I found it by myself in the android framework source, which can be browsed for example here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/master/services/sensorservice/

Comment: well, according to Android API specification, sensors: TYPE_GRAVITY, TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION and TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR were introduced already in API 9. Are those sensors fusions you're talking about, or you mean something else?

Comment: Seems that the project structure was changed again, since I cannot find it under the provided link anymore.